# can a regular webhost and a separate node js server communicate?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, node.js

I'm currently working on a trade / social network site as a side/learning/fun project.

At the moment I have an sql database messaging system. I want to create a live chat system like facebook which can tell the user is online, typing a message and everything.

I did some research into this and figured I need to start learning to use node.js and websockets. I called my webhost and they said they don't support node.js. I like the tools I'm using and do not want to migrate my website.

I also looked into some info about CORS.

I was thinking of a solution: client as well as the php server also communicates with an external node.js server using jquery to handle all chat and notification requests. The node.js server will also store messages in the php servers mysql database.

Is this solution feasible and am I on the right track? Or is there a better way?

Comment: php supports sockets http://socketo.me/

Comment: Technically speaking I don't see any problem here. PHP and node.js can talk to each other with no issues as long as they speak a "language" they can both understand(json probably in this case). As for the data in the database, well, it's just that. Data. Any programming language can read that. Logistically speaking you'll run into a lot of issues making them play nice.

Comment: It's an overkill. The reason you want to use node.js is speed and concurrency. Once you put a layer of PHP on top of it you'll lose all of that. Using PHP just because your host doesn't support node and you don't want to switch is not a good enough reason at least to me.

Comment: But can client side of one website communicate with a backend of another server?

Comment: Or are php sockets just as effective?